# How to retrieve rows multiple times in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

These are my rows that I initially retrieved:

```
112   Cem   Ceminay
210   Ali   Salih
132   Gül   Sen
```

Now I want to clone every row to be duplicated as 3 rows. So the new results:

```
112   Cem   Ceminay
112   Cem   Ceminay
112   Cem   Ceminay
210   Ali   Salih
210   Ali   Salih
210   Ali   Salih
132   Gül   Sen
132   Gül   Sen
132   Gül   Sen
```

What kind of select statement can help me?

Example select statement:

```
SELECT id,name,surname FROM people;
```

Thank you lovely people...

PS: My query:

```
            SELECT 
        Faturalar.faturaNo
        ,Klinikler.SAPSirketKodu [COMPANY CODE]
        ,Klinikler.SAPBussinessArea [BUSINESS AREA]
        ,BasilmisFaturalar.basilmisFatura_id [REFERENCE]
        ,BasilmisFaturalar.duzenlemeTarihi [DOCUMENT DATE]
        ,BasilmisFaturalar.duzenlemeTarihi [BASELINE DATE]
        ,Kurumlar.sapKodu [ACCOUNT]
        ,Kurumlar.kurumAdi + ' adına '+Faturalar.faturaNo+' nolu fatura' [TEXT]
        ,BasilmisFaturalar.kdvDahilToplamTutar [AMOUNT]
        ,BasilmisFaturalar.kdvHaricToplamTutar
        ,(BasilmisFaturalar.kdvDahilToplamTutar-BasilmisFaturalar.kdvHaricToplamTutar) AS kdvTutari
        ,CASE 
        WHEN BasilmisFaturalar.kdvOrani = 0 THEN 'A0'
        WHEN BasilmisFaturalar.kdvOrani = 8 THEN '2H'
        WHEN BasilmisFaturalar.kdvOrani = 18 THEN '3H'
        END [TAX CODE]
        ,Klinikler.profitCenter [COST CENTER/PROFIT CENTER]
        FROM Faturalar 
        -- Fatura yazdırılmış olmalı
        INNER JOIN BasilmisFaturalar ON BasilmisFaturalar.basilmisFatura_id = Faturalar.refBasilmisFatura_id
        -- Yazdırılmış fatura iptal edilmemiş olmalı
        INNER JOIN BasiliFaturaIptalTalepleri ON BasiliFaturaIptalTalepleri.refBasilmisFatura_id <> BasilmisFaturalar.basilmisFatura_id
        -- Fatura Kurum Detaylarından KURUM bilgilerine
        INNER JOIN KurumFaturaDetaylari ON KurumFaturaDetaylari.kurumFaturaDetay_id = BasilmisFaturalar.refKurumFaturaDetay_id
        -- Faturanın kesildiği kurum
        INNER JOIN Kurumlar ON Kurumlar.kurum_id = dbo.KurumFaturaDetaylari.refKurum_id
        -- Seanslar üzerinden Klinik bilgilerine böylece SAPcc, SAPba, ProfitCenter a ulaşıyoruz
        INNER JOIN Seanslar ON Seanslar.refFatura_id = Faturalar.fatura_id

        INNER JOIN dbo.Klinikler ON dbo.Klinikler.klinik_id = Seanslar.refKlinik_id
        -- Belirli bir düzenleme tarihi aralığında olmalı
        WHERE BasilmisFaturalar.duzenlemeTarihi BETWEEN DATEADD(m,-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
        GROUP BY Faturalar.faturaNo,BasilmisFaturalar.basilmisFatura_id,kdvDahilToplamTutar
        ,kdvHaricToplamTutar
        ,BasilmisFaturalar.kdvOrani
        ,BasilmisFaturalar.duzenlemeTarihi
        ,Kurumlar.sapKodu
        ,Klinikler.SAPBussinessArea
        ,Klinikler.SAPSirketKodu
        ,Klinikler.profitCenter
        ,Kurumlar.kurumAdi
```

Comment: Why in God's name would you want to do this?

Comment: @JohnFx: that wasn't the question! :-)

Comment: @marc_s: at least he said this in a comment instead of an answer.  @JohnFx: surely you've had the SO experience of posting a question and having everyone assume what you're trying to do is retarded.  It's not very polite, in my opinion.  Just answer the question as it's posted.

Comment: And what does God have to do with this?  God can't code.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I disagree...I think it can be very valid to ask why a person is doing something that seems a bit (or more than a bit) unusual.  It can be a sign that something is wrong, and sometimes they're barking up the wrong tree, and are asking a question that can be avoided by simply approaching the problem in a different and better way.

Comment: because i will export invoices to sap.To do this i have to clone a row to three rows..

Comment: I can see both sides. Assuming sensible motivation, in this case, RDBMS are designed to work with sets and it's easy to implement.

Comment: @Musi: I'm sure he has as I'm sure you have, and I have, and most people who've posted lots of questions to SO have. This is a community moderated site and a little peer review is certainly healthy.

Comment: @Beska: your points are of course valid, so long as the issues are raised politely and respectfully.  Example: "Why do you need to do this?"  As it turns out, uzay has a perfectly valid reason to do this (if you consider SAP to be perfectly valid).

Comment: @Jason: please tell me God has the curly braces on separate lines.

Comment: @Musi: In the most polite way this can be said, if your skin is so thin as to be insulted on the interwebs by a comment like "Why in God's name would you want to do this?", then you should likely pursue other avenues of investigating a solution. This seems like greatly protracted discussion for such a simple, relatively harmless comment.

Comment: "There is no God but Allah, and he's object-oriented".

Comment: @Adam: I was insulted on behalf of the poster, who is new to this site. My own skin thickness is fine. This is a protracted discussion because I'm bored and waiting for dinner.

Comment: @uzay95: I've updated my answer with your original query copy+pasted

Comment: Thank you gbn.. BTW, God,Allah,Tengri ... is one and He is closer to you then your own vein. ;)

Comment: @Musi: He has nearly 350 points and several questions...wouldn't say he's completely new here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To help explain: [Cartesian product/cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) background

```
SELECT
    people.id, people.name, people.surname
FROM
    people
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 1 AS foo UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) bar;
```

After comment elsewhere about 7 tables and 42 lines

```
SELECT
    Singles.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
    Faturalar.faturaNo
    ,Klinikler.SAPSirketKodu [COMPANY CODE]
    ,Klinikler.SAPBussinessArea [BUSINESS AREA]
    ,BasilmisFaturalar.basilmisFatura_id [REFERENCE]
    ,BasilmisFaturalar.duzenlemeTarihi [DOCUMENT DATE]
    ,BasilmisFaturalar.duzenlemeTarihi [BASELINE DATE]
    ,Kurumlar.sapKodu [ACCOUNT]
    ,Kurumlar.kurumAdi + ' adına '+Faturalar.faturaNo+' nolu fatura' [TEXT]
    ,BasilmisFaturalar.kdvDahilToplamTutar [AMOUNT]
    ,BasilmisFaturalar.kdvHaricToplamTutar
    ,(BasilmisFaturalar.kdvDahilToplamTutar-BasilmisFaturalar.kdvHaricToplamTutar) AS kdvTutari
    ,CASE 
    WHEN BasilmisFaturalar.kdvOrani = 0 THEN 'A0'
    WHEN BasilmisFaturalar.kdvOrani = 8 THEN '2H'
    WHEN BasilmisFaturalar.kdvOrani = 18 THEN '3H'
    END [TAX CODE]
    ,Klinikler.profitCenter [COST CENTER/PROFIT CENTER]
    FROM Faturalar 
    -- Fatura yazdırılmış olmalı
    INNER JOIN BasilmisFaturalar ON BasilmisFaturalar.basilmisFatura_id = Faturalar.refBasilmisFatura_id
    -- Yazdırılmış fatura iptal edilmemiş olmalı
    INNER JOIN BasiliFaturaIptalTalepleri ON BasiliFaturaIptalTalepleri.refBasilmisFatura_id <> BasilmisFaturalar.basilmisFatura_id
    -- Fatura Kurum Detaylarından KURUM bilgilerine
    INNER JOIN KurumFaturaDetaylari ON KurumFaturaDetaylari.kurumFaturaDetay_id = BasilmisFaturalar.refKurumFaturaDetay_id
    -- Faturanın kesildiği kurum
    INNER JOIN Kurumlar ON Kurumlar.kurum_id = dbo.KurumFaturaDetaylari.refKurum_id
    -- Seanslar üzerinden Klinik bilgilerine böylece SAPcc, SAPba, ProfitCenter a ulaşıyoruz
    INNER JOIN Seanslar ON Seanslar.refFatura_id = Faturalar.fatura_id

    INNER JOIN dbo.Klinikler ON dbo.Klinikler.klinik_id = Seanslar.refKlinik_id
    -- Belirli bir düzenleme tarihi aralığında olmalı
    WHERE BasilmisFaturalar.duzenlemeTarihi BETWEEN DATEADD(m,-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
    GROUP BY Faturalar.faturaNo,BasilmisFaturalar.basilmisFatura_id,kdvDahilToplamTutar
    ,kdvHaricToplamTutar
    ,BasilmisFaturalar.kdvOrani
    ,BasilmisFaturalar.duzenlemeTarihi
    ,Kurumlar.sapKodu
    ,Klinikler.SAPBussinessArea
    ,Klinikler.SAPSirketKodu
    ,Klinikler.profitCenter
    ,Kurumlar.kurumAdi
    ) Singles
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 1 AS foo UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) Multiplier;
```

Comment: Interesting approach - it might not duplicate the query, but it's not easily and quite obvious at first what this does, in my opinion.

Comment: @marc: I disagree...seems pretty obvious to me.

Comment: @marc_s, true. Slightly more opaque but perhaps slightly more correct, for us anyway. Personally, I'd cross join against my handy numbers table though :-)

Comment: as I said - very interesting approach, I'll have to remember that - not sure if it's quite obvious at first sight to a SQL beginner, though (Adam and you are obviously both quite advanced, but will a SQL beginner "grok" this right away? I have my doubts).....

Comment: @marc: Probably not, but that's why it's good to give a solution like that in this context. The output and goal is clearly defined, and the query is short. It shouldn't be too tough to pick it up :)

Comment: I'm not exactly a SQL beginner, and it took me a second to figure out why this was working.  I think a beginner would have some trouble...though if there were a comment along with the statement explaining what it did, it would be fine, and a very slick way to accomplish it.

Comment: I think it would be upvoted more if he explained what the query was doing.  To that end: It is using a table valued subquery with 3 rows which is named bar.  It then does a cross join which is the same as an inner join with 1=1 as the criteria.  It produces what is called a cartesian product but which is just one row from the first table for each row in the second table.  Since there are 3 rows in the second table, bar, it produces 3 copies of the row from the first table, people.  To adjust the number of copies, just adjust the number of rows in the second table, bar.

Comment: @Will Rickards: Cartesian products are part of the basics for SQL language. Even your explanation mentions it. We have to assume someone knows what this is... and they know the outer/inner/cross join basics too. Anyone who joins in the where clause is using a cartesian product (as implicit cross join) too.

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
SELECT id,name,surname FROM people
UNION ALL
SELECT id,name,surname FROM people
UNION ALL
SELECT id,name,surname FROM people
```

and possibly add a

```
ORDER BY id, name
```

to it if you want it ordered.

Marc

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say.  +1

Comment: I want to multiply result :) Isn't exist anyway can quickly multiply resultset.Because my sql statement 42 lines and contains 7 tables

Comment: @uzay: can you use gbn's answer? that might work better in your scenario then.

Comment: @uzay: something like this, selecting the same rows multiple times, isn't something that's done very often, so I guess that's why there's no real "out-of-the-box" support for it in SQL Server

Comment: @marc_s: absoultly this is the first time i needed something like that. This will be reduce my code behind codes.